# Polymer iron-list set items to php array/json

Tags: php, arrays, json, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have an iron list and I want to populate it with either a php array or a raw json string (it could be either or, doesn't matter to me)

In the past I have set the list items by a url using the iron-ajax component and supplying a url.  Now I have to set the list items from either a php array that is populated on the same page as the iron-list or I can json_encode the array and use that for the list items if the list requires that instead of the array.  I can't seem to figure it out though, I'm not getting any items in the list (I know the array is populated)

the php I use to fill the array and I'm also json encoding it because I've been playing with supplying the iron list either the array or the json to get it to work: This is done on the same page as the list right above it pretty much

```
$projects=array();
$projects=getUserProjects(100);
$jsonresult=json_encode($projects);
```

now in my iron list I have been trying to set the items various ways but none seem to be working I've tried:

```
<iron-list items="<?php echo $jsonresult;?>" as="item">
<iron-list items="{{<?php echo $jsonresult;?>}}" as="item">
<iron-list items="[[<?php echo $jsonresult;?>]]" as="item">
<iron-list items="<?php print_r ($projects);?>" as="item">
<iron-list items="[[<?php print_r ($projects);?>]]" as="item">
<iron-list items="{{<?php print_r($projects);?>}}" as="item">
```

When I view the source I can see it's echoing out the json or the array but it's not displaying anything in the list.

How can I use either the array or the json string on the same local page to populate the list? All the examples I have seen only use URL's to populate the list.

Edit:  I also tried setting the iron-ajax url to just the json string like this:

```
<iron-ajax url="<?php echo $jsonresult;?>"  last-response="{{data}}" auto
</iron-ajax>

<iron-list items="[[data]]" as="item">
```

But that didn't work either.

I also tried what the first person commented.. json_decode like this:

```
$projects=array();
$projects=getUserProjects(100);
$jsonresult=json_encode($projects);
$jsonde=json_decode($projects);

<iron-list items="[[<?php print_r ($jsonde);?>]]" as="item">
```

And that also did not work

Comment: You have to json_decode and use it accordingly.

Comment: So I would first have to convert the array to json then decode the json?

Comment: That did not work and it seems silly that I have an array, I have to convert it to json just to decode it again.  

So now I have also tried:
    $projects=array();
   $projects=getUserProjects(100);
  $jsonresult=json_encode($projects); $jsonde=json_decode($jsonresult);
<iron-list items="{{<?php print_r($jsonde);?>}}" as="item"> and that didn't work either

Comment: you are using {{data}}  and [[data]] for the $root element ( req'd for ajax ) and for $array element ( req'd for the list ). DONT use same for both. Look at your php response ( JSON ) and distinguish the root ele name from the array name and use them respectively to BIND the ajax vs bind the list.

Comment: Actually I got the answer on the Slack channel.  All I had to do was this:
  <iron-list items='<?php echo $jsonresult;?>' as="item">

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer on the Polymer Slack channel from user trakkasure
 I just had to pass it in like this with the single quotes and no brackets and it loaded the list as it should.

```
<iron-list items='<?php echo $jsonresult;?>' as="item">
```